# using .htaccess to force some pages using non-SSL on an SSL site

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, flash

I currently have a site where users can login and do various things. The site uses SSL(HTTPS).

Is there a way to use .php or .htaccess to unsecure a specific link and any link connected (ie. (https://domain.com/unsecure, https://domain.com/unsecure/randominfinit)) unsecure?

But also would this work with a user being logged in to their account and be able to navigate out of /unsecure or /unsecure/randominfinit and still be logged in and not throw errors or browser errors or reduce security?

I have been looking everywhere for a solution for this and have not been able yet to find a solution.

The reason why I need to do this is because I am using iframe to load .swf content on my secure site that is hosted on another domain/server. If you have a better idea to deliver content using iframe with non-SSL content, please tell me - I am all ears.

Comment: A huge block of text tends to be unreadable - separated it out into paragraphs and fixed some typos.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a valid cert you can go between http and https. This will check if the directory is unsecure and https then redirect to non https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/unsecure [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I do need the entire site using SSL, just need the /unsecure and all affected /unsecure/random associated with the original /unsecure to be unsecure. This is only to display content on another domain which I am using iframe. Thank you

Comment: This rule I provide only affects the /unsecure folder on your server. So the rest of the site will still be https. Did you try it?

Comment: ok I do see that now, It kind of works. It does redirect to http instead of https but browsers dont display content and throw error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: Do you have something linked? How are you calling that page or iframe? Are you using a relative URL or absolute?